# sub isn't replacing values

Tags: r, string

I am using this command to replace strings with numeric values. This command has been working well for every string I have come across; however, it hasn't been replacing the string "High Display (3+)". Is there something about this string that makes the sub command not function, or do you think I have a typo somewhere in my data (I double checked, and I don't see any)?

```
my.Data$dataColumn <- sub("High Display (3+)", 2, my.Data$dataColumn)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Note that `sub` and `gsub`, by default, are using regular expression based replacement (`fixed=FALSE`). The `(`, `)` and `+` are special regex metacharacters that must be escaped to be parsed as literal chars.

See  [this demo](http://ideone.com/9uQEyn):

```
sub("High Display \\(3\\+\\)", 2, s)
```

If you replace literal strings, use `fixed=TRUE`:

```
s <- "High Display (3+)"
sub("High Display (3+)", 2, s, fixed=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](http://ideone.com/9BGjH2)